# Using a custom domain with a Heroku hosted app

Tags: heroku, dns

I am trying to point a custom doamin provided by Domain.com to my Heroku app. Everything works well unless I try to enter a direct URL past the normal landing page.

If I go to `mycustomdomain.com` I get the right landing page and can navigate throughout the site. However, If I go directly to a URL deeper insite the site such as `mycustomdomain.com/widgets` I get a 404 error. But, if I go to myapp.herokuapp.com/widgets everything works fine.

Another ofdity is that when I go to `mycustomdomain.com` no matter where I navigate the url is always diaplyed as `mycustomdomain.com` with nothing ever trailing.

Comment: In your app, do you use the HTML5 history api? Is it a "single page app"? Also, do you have any server-side code that looks at the domain name? Could you post some code?

Comment: How have you 'pointed' your custom domain at Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue with Domain.com's configuration. No matter what I tried I could not get the domain the redirect properly. I switched to GoDaddy and used the exact same configuration and everything worked great.